# Add asp.net button control into master page list item?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In the master page i have list item

```html
<ul id="ulmain">
       <li >Home</li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a button control in a webform which is using that masterpage .

```
<asp:Button ID="signOutButton" runat="server"Text="Sign out" />
```

Now from this webform i want to bind this button control into masterpage list item . How can i achieve that

Comment: Why dont just keep the button in the master page?

Comment: In the master page it should be placed within a form control . If i add this button on master page this button will be bind every webform . I dont want this . I want to bind a specific button from a specific webform

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ContentPlaceHolder named by ButtonContent

```html
<ul id="ulmain">
   <li >Home</li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   <li>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ButtonContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your webform use that ContentPlaceHolder and show your buton

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ButtonContent" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="signOutButton" runat="server"Text="Sign out" />
</asp:Content>
```